# Add custom controls to AVPlayer in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avplayer, avplayeritem

I am trying to create a table view such that I am able to play videos . I am able to do this using AVPlayer and layer.

I want to add a custom play and pause button with a slider to the bottom of a video view.

AVPlayerController comes built in with these controls.

How can I implement these in AVPlayer. I have been looking for examples. But I haven't found any.

Are there any GitHub examples or code samples that I can follow? Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you have a look at Apple's Sample Code? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: you need to hide the custom control an create own

Comment: I am looking for swift examples

Answer (score 50, accepted):

here I add the points , you need to customize based on your need.

**Step-1**

initially hide your `AVPlayer` controls,

```
 YourAVPlayerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = false
```

**Step-2**

create the structure like

[image]

> one label for current Duration, One label for overall Duration, one UIbutton for pause and play your current player and one UISlider for seek The video.

**step-3**

initially close the simple steps.

> first stop and play the player using button action , currentPlayer is your AVPlayer name.

```
@IBAction func handlePlayPauseButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
   //  sender.isSelected ?  currentPlayer.pause() :   currentPlayer.play()
    if sender.isSelected {
        currentPlayer.pause()
    }
    else {
        currentPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

> second set the video duration, as like

```
    let duration : CMTime = currentPlayer.currentItem!.asset.duration
    let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)

    lblOverallDuration.text = self.stringFromTimeInterval(interval: seconds)
```

> third set the player current time to current duration label

```
    let duration : CMTime = currentPlayer.currentTime()
    let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)

    lblcurrentText.text = self.stringFromTimeInterval(interval: seconds)
```

> the following method is convert from NSTimeinterval to HH:MM:SS

```
func stringFromTimeInterval(interval: TimeInterval) -> String {

    let interval = Int(interval)
    let seconds = interval % 60
    let minutes = (interval / 60) % 60
    let hours = (interval / 3600)
    return String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
}
```

> finally we go for slider control for calulate the seek time

```
_playheadSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handlePlayheadSliderTouchBegin), for: .touchDown)
_playheadSlider.addTarget(self, action:    #selector(self.handlePlayheadSliderTouchEnd), for: .touchUpInside)
_playheadSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handlePlayheadSliderTouchEnd), for: .touchUpOutside)
_playheadSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handlePlayheadSliderValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
```

> lets we go for action, initially when touchbegin is start then stop the player
>
> handlePlayheadSliderTouchBegin

```
@IBAction func handlePlayheadSliderTouchBegin(_ sender: UISlider) {
currentPlayer.pause()
}
```

> set the current item label for calculate the `sender.value * CMTimeGetSeconds(currentPlayer.currentItem.duration)`

```
@IBAction func handlePlayheadSliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

        let duration : CMTime = currentPlayer.currentItem!.asset.duration
     let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration) * sender.value
 //   var newCurrentTime: TimeInterval = sender.value * CMTimeGetSeconds(currentPlayer.currentItem.duration)
lblcurrentText.text = self.stringFromTimeInterval(interval: seconds)
   }
```

> finally move the player based on seek

```
 @IBAction func handlePlayheadSliderTouchEnd(_ sender: UISlider) {

  let duration : CMTime = currentPlayer.currentItem!.asset.duration
var newCurrentTime: TimeInterval = sender.value * CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
var seekToTime: CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(newCurrentTime, 600)
currentPlayer.seek(toTime: seekToTime)
}
```

Comment: very detailed answer :)

Comment: How to go fullscreen?

Comment: @BhavinRamani - based on question I added the answer, if you need to go full screen, need to add one more button and inside the action use transform rotate

Comment: @Anbu.karthik how do you add this custom view over avplayer?

Comment: @SyedAliSalman - initally create one UIView (yourview addsubvew.avplayer) then add customview (yourview.addview.customview)

Comment: that is we don't add over AVPlayerController.view? right?

Comment: Thanks. I was adding over AVPlayerController.view and it was not appearing right.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, Thanks Your Great Answer!!. Can we add zoom on double tap or two fingers on player when "showsPlaybackControls = false" is false?

Comment: UISlider not updating on playing video, it's a bug so not complete answer. Kindly update answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Anbu.Karthik's answer, the slider handing can be handled better in a single function like below:

```
slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handlePlayheadSliderValueChanged(sender:event:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

Slider Value Change:

***Note switch cases handling all phases of slider event***

```
@objc func handlePlayheadSliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider, event: UIEvent) {
    if let duration: CMTime = player?.currentItem?.asset.duration {
        let newCurrentTime: Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration) * Double(sender.value)
        videoLengthLabel.text = self.stringFromTimeInterval(interval: newCurrentTime)
        if let touchEvent = event.allTouches?.first {
            switch (touchEvent.phase) {
            case .began:
                // on slider touch begin
                pauseVideo()
                break
            case .moved:
                // on slider movement
                let seekToTime: CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(newCurrentTime, preferredTimescale: 600)
                player?.seek(to: seekToTime, completionHandler: { (completedSeek) in
                    // any additional operation upon seek completion
                })
                break
            case .ended:
                // on slider touch end (finger lift)
                playVideo()
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```