# Play audio from "paused" point after restarting the track with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I'm working on a music player in Swift. The user can play a track, pause the track, or move a slider to choose a place to start. These three functions work.

However, if a user plays a track, listens for 1:00, and hits pause: when they click play again, it will restart the track from 0:00 instead of respecting where they paused.

I am using `AVAudioPlayer` as a media player -- according to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/1386886-preparetoplay), `.play()` allows you to specify a start-point using `atTime`.

So I tried to use `atTime` and have it start where the slider is -- if a listener listens for 1:00, I want `atTime` to dynamically pick that up. I try to establish this time value in a var.

```
class MusicViewController: UIViewController {
// removed imports and viewdidload to condense

    @IBAction func playDownload(_ sender: Any) { 
    // removed file download code to condense

        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: destinationUrl)
            guard let player = audioPlayer else { return }

            //here's where I try to capture a time value from the slider's progress
            let checkTime = TimeInterval(Slider.value)

            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play(atTime: checkTime)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        // updates slider with progress
        Slider.value = 0.0
        Slider.maximumValue = Float((audioPlayer?.duration)!)
        audioPlayer.play()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.0001, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateSlider), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @IBAction func pause(_ sender: Any) {

        if audioPlayer.isPlaying {
            audioPlayer.pause()
        } else {
            audioPlayer.play()
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet var Slider: UISlider!

    @objc func updateSlider() {

        Slider.value = Float(audioPlayer.currentTime)
        print("Changing works")
    }
}
```

So I am trying to capture progress and have .play respect that -- this code will run, but it does not work. No errors but after hitting play, it will go to the end of the track immediately now. No good.

I am new to Swift - any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: once you paused the avplayer just invalidate the time and once you start the play resume the timer

Comment: hey, I tried that and changed the pause function to the following but it still goes to the end of the file when I hit play -- testing right now to see if I can find out what isn't working. `  @IBAction func pause(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if  audioPlayer.isPlaying{
            audioPlayer.pause()
            timer?.invalidate()
        }else{
            audioPlayer.play()
        }
    }`

Comment: see this one may be it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062870/add-custom-controls-to-avplayer-in-swift/43070099#43070099