# Swift 4 - AVAudioPlayer set currentTime from UISlider

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I have a `UISlider` and `AvAudioPlayer`, currently I am able to set the `UISlider`  to the `currentTime` of a `AvAudioPlayer` like so:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: (#selector(RecordController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func updateTimer() {
    if(audio != nil) {
       audioSlider.setValue(Float((self.audio?.currentTime)! / (self.audio?.duration)!), animated: false)
    }
}
```

But how would I set the `currentTime` of the `AVAudioPlayer` when changing the value of the `UISlider`?

```
@IBAction func audioSliderUpdated(_ sender: Any) {
}
```

Comment: see this for e.g : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062870/add-custom-controls-to-avplayer-in-swift/43070099#43070099

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the currentTime property of AVAudioPlayer:

```
@IBAction func audioSliderUpdated(_ sender: Any) {
  if let slider = sender as? UISlider {
    self.audio?.currentTime = slider.value    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this, slider value changes according to time

```
 @IBAction func slide(_ sender: UISlider) {
    self.audio.currentTime = TimeInterval(slider.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your slider value to a new value which based on your media file.

First, you must config your slider values to work in normalized values (from 0.0 to 1.0)

```
/// call this on viewDidLoad: configDefaults(for: audioSlider)
func configDefaults(for slider: UISlider)
    slider.minimumValue = 0.0
    slider.maximumValue = 1.0
}
```

Then you should calculate `currentTime` from `audioSlider.value` and `duration` then set it to the `player.currentTime`.

```
@IBAction func audioSliderUpdated(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let slider = sender as? UISlider,
        let player = audio else {
        return
    }
    player.currentTime = Double(slider.value) * player.duration
}
```