# Getting Duration of AVPlayer in minutes

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, avplayer

I am trying to get the duration of an `AVPlayer` asset in Hours, Minutes, Seconds. I am able to get the time but it seems to be in seconds and milliseconds.

This is how I get the time:

```
let duration : CMTime = (player.currentItem!.asset.duration)!
let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
```

I am then applying that to a slider using

```
slider.maximumValue = Float(seconds)
```

The outcome of this obviously gives me the duration in seconds however I want to be able to use the duration to set the `maximumValue` of my slider for video clips which may be under a minute.

For Example: My code above returns 30.865 for a 30 second clip. I need it to return 0.30

Comment: How 30 seconds can be 0.30 minute ?

Comment: Yes, currently the slider for a 0.30 video take 30 minutes to reach the end

Comment: 30 is just an example. a 5 minute clip sets the slider at 306.87323. I need to know how to set the slider to match my clip length

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062870/add-custom-controls-to-avplayer-in-swift/43070099#43070099

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me:

```
let duration : CMTime = (player.currentItem!.asset.duration)!
let timeInMinutes = Float(duration.value)
```